# 2N7000 level shifter doesn't work under a certain voltage

Tags: voltage-divider, level-shifting

I need to convert a 1.8V UART line to 3.4V.

I don't have the 1.8V voltage reference available, but I have the 3.4V reference, so I'm using a voltage divider to get about 1.8V.

This is my circuit:

[image: The described circuit]

However, it doesn't work for Vcc = 3.4V. In fact, it only works for Vcc > ~5V.
Why's that?

Comment: Have you seen the datasheet yet?

Comment: The body diode is backwards. The 2N7000 is NMOS, and the diode is reverse biased when Vd > Vs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2N7000 datasheet I just looked at shows a \$V_{GS(th)}\$ with a minimum of 0.8V and a maximum of 3.0V. When \$V_{TX1.8} = 0V\$, I'd imagine you'd want \$V_{GS} \ge 3.0V\$ so that you can expect the 2N7000 to be ON and pulling down on the 10k\$\Omega\$ output pull-up and presenting about 0V at the \$V_{TX3.4}\$ side of things. Then when \$V_{TX1.8} = 1.8V\$, I'd imagine you'd want \$V_{GS} \le 0.8V\$ so that you can expect the 2N7000 to be OFF and allowing the 10k\$\Omega\$ output pull-up to do its job and present about 3.4V at the \$V_{TX3.4}\$ side of things. Isn't that about it?

The problem is that you can't easily have both cases here, if you can only set the gate voltage with a resistor divider. You'd need to have \$V_G \ge 3.0V\$ in one case and \$V_G \le 2.6V\$ in the other case. So if I were stuck with the 2N7000 and planning on shooting for a circuit that will *probably* work okay, I'd probably give up and set \$V_G \approx 2.5V\$ and just go with that.

This brings up another thing. You've got a 10k\$\Omega\$ resistor going from the resistor divider node back to the \$V_{TX1.8}\$ node (source.) Why? This actually moves the gate closer to ground at a time when you'd like it further away, and visa versa. I think I'd dump that. It could just be that I'm ignorant (I'm just a hobbyist and have no formal training at all in electronics.) But it doesn't make any sense to me, right now. It actually seems to push things the wrong way -- to me, anyway.

So perhaps try something like this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5puWE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now:

\$V_{TX1.8} = 0V \rightarrow V_{GS} = 2.45V\$, transistor is \$\approx\$ ON

\$V_{TX1.8} = 1.8V \rightarrow V_{GS} = 0.65V\$, transistor is \$\approx\$ OFF

Which I think should do about what you want.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted. I have no electronics education whatsoever and I'm just beginning to understand something.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: would a lower threshold FET (such as the BSS88, with max threshold = 1.2V) work in my original circuit?

Comment: You don't write the minimum. But given the logic I spelled out above, you should be able to work that out, now. If you have difficulty, write again and I'll add something to help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to implement the famous upside-down FET level shifter circuit. But there are some mistakes. Here is a link to where it is done correctly:

[image: famous upside-down FET level shifter]

Note that they use the BSS138 which is definitely a better choice (works at lower voltages). They connect the source to the low-voltage side and the drain to the high voltage side (opposite of what you have drawn). The gate is directly connected to the low-voltage power rail (you connected to high side with voltage divider).

If you fix the mistakes, even the 2N7000 may work, but at 1.8V, it is definitely marginal.

Comment: The high side is connected to Vcc, not to the voltage divider. As jonk pointed out, the problem seems to be the threshold for the 2N7000.

Comment: Well, it would really help if you drew the symbol correctly. Normally when you draw the gate off to one side, it is on the source side. I guess you drew the gate on the drain side, which really confused me. Do you think you could fix it?